# Call function from Ajax reloaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery

With an Ajax request I reload a page and based on some conditions from the database I want to call a JavaScript function on the main page (because I need some variables from the main page).

PHP code:

```
if($reset_regionaal == 1 OR $reset_landelijk == 1 OR $reset_extra == 1){
    echo "<script>window.resetopties(".$reset_regionaal.",".$reset_landelijk.",".$reset_regionaal.");</script>";
 }
```

JS code:

```
function resetopties(regionaal_opvallen_reset, landelijk_opvallen_reset, extra_opvallen_reset){
    alert(regionaal_opvallen);
};
```

But it does not work, it does not execute the function. The function is simplified of course

Comment: we need some code to help you

Comment: Can you please show the code you wrote that produced this problem?

Comment: Edited the post with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is called before it is defined, it won't execute and will cause an error.

Comment: I define it on document ready, when the page is reloaded the function should be available because the page is already loaded.

Comment: If the function is defined on document ready but the function is executed before the document is ready (in a script tag in the body of the document), it will error out. Try calling the function in the document ready, after the definition.

Comment: @Jilco: If it is defined inside the `ready` callback, then the function is not global and cannot be found. Define it outside of the handler or make it explicitly global: `window.resetopties = function(...) {...};`. Then it also depends on how actually include the server response into the page. E.g. using `innerHTML` will strip all `script` tags.

Comment: Thanks all, i placed the function outside the document ready and that solved the problem. Strange but it works

Comment: @Jilco: What is it that you find strange? If you define a function/variable inside a function, you cannot access it from the outside. Example: `function foo() { var a = 1; }; foo(); alert(a);` You won't be able to access `a` outside of the function because it it is only defined in the *scope* of the function. The same happens if you define the function inside the `ready` callback. You cannot access it outside the callback (and the script you load *is* outside the callback).